# Reshape multi-header table in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and trying to reshape table from excel file as I have multiple header I am trying to convert first header into 2 separate column. i am attaching my code output and data here.
[Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UtNH.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm

df = pd.read_excel(r'.\test.xlsx', header=[0, 1])
df = (df.stack(0, dropna=False)
        .rename_axis(index=('Customer','Date'), columns=None)
        .reset_index())
df.to_csv(r'.\testnew.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

Printed Output - [image]

Desired Output -

| Customer | Date | Budget | Actual | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Jan-20 | 100 | 50 | 0 |
| John | Feb-20 |  |  |  |
| John | Mar-20 |  |  |  |
| Chris | Jan-20 | 120 | 80 | 0 |
| Chris | Feb-20 | 50 | 10 | 20 |
| Chris | Mar-20 | 50 | 45 |  |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'.\test.xlsx', header=[0, 1])

df = (df.stack(0, dropna=False)
        .rename_axis(index=('Customer','Date'), columns=None)
        .reset_index())
```

Comment: Not working properly it converted the first row into a column but it is giving multiple columns with the same column name and empty rows. something like customer name, Date, Actual, ACtual, Amount1,Amount2,Amount3....

Comment: @Annie - So it means there are typos in columns names? Is possible use `df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lower())` after `df = pd.read_excel(r'.\test.xlsx', header=[0, 1])`?

Comment: I have tried using lower but date doesn't have lower value so getting error. I have also attached the current output with the edited code on post.Please suggest  @jezrael

Comment: @Annie - How working change `df = pd.read_excel(r'.\test.xlsx', header=[0, 1])` to `df = pd.read_excel(r'.\test.xlsx', header=[0, 1], index_col=[0])` ?

Comment: Thank you it is giving better results just that column name Actual is coming twice the same as in above result picture. Rest is perfectly OK. @jezrael

Comment: @Annie - good news. what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` after my solution? Because reason why duoble actual should be some whitespace like `'actual'` and `'actual '`

Comment: Got it... Thank you so much it is working fine now.

Comment: @Annie - Supeeer! Glad can help you.